# DataTables Server side processing with link dillemma

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using `DataTables` to display 100k+ of records with success, but now i cannot add a custom link to the table because is generated with JavaScript where i get a bit lost.
what i want to achieve is the last column to display a link similar to this: `a href="index.php?edit=ID"` where id is the `id` from the db.

You can be seen the PHP and HTML used in this below:

```
<?php
    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array( 'first_name', 'last_name', 'afiliere', 'user', 'parola', 'activ', 'id' );

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "useri";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "_summon";
    $gaSql['server']     = "";


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /*
     * MySQL connection
     */
    $gaSql['link'] =  mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) or
        die( 'Could not open connection to server' );

    mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) or
        die( 'Could not select database '. $gaSql['db'] );


    /*
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /*
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

and the html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>DataTables example</title>
        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "media/css/demo_page.css";
            @import "media/css/demo_table.css";
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "1.php"
                } );
            } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="dt_example">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="demo">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>hjghkj</th>
            <th>hgjkghj</th>
            <th>ghjkghk</th>
            <th>ghjkghjk</th>
            <th>ghjkghjk</th>
            <th>ghjkghjkgh</th>
            <th>dfgdfgdg</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>asdasd</td>
            <td colspan="6" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>sdfgd</th>
            <th>dsfgsdfgdsg</th>
            <th>sdfgsdfg</th>
            <th>sdgsdfgsdfg</th>
            <th>sdfgsdfgsd</th>
            <th>sdfgsdfgsd</th>
            <th>dfgdfgd</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Check fnRowCallback [here](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
      // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
      if ( aData[4] == "A" )
      {
        $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>A</b>' ); // You can add your link here!!
//like $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<a href="'+ aData[4] +'">Click Here</b>' );
       }
    }
  } );
} );
```

`aData` is an object which contains in an array, per row basis, your content that's coming from your server. So in your case it may not necessarily be `aData[4]`, it could be `1,2,3` depends in which `column` your `id` comes.

You can do a `console.log(aData)` in your case to analyze as into which column, your id resides in! (You will need [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for this)

Also `td:eq(4)` is again the column where you wish display the link at.

Comment: it works but i cannot generate the id for each row. I tried: $('td:eq(6)', nRow).html( '<a href="index.php?edit='+aData[6]'">Edit</a>' ); // You can add your link here!! but with no success